# Reduce the number of stack trace frames when logging an exception in Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, serilog, .net-8.0

When logging an exception in `ASP.NET`, the stack trace usually runs as long as your arm. I don't need the complete stack trace when e.g. an entity isn't found in the database. I'd like to limit it - either to just the first frame of the stack trace, or if that isn't possible then just the exception message.

I'm using `Serilog` with `ASP.NET (Core) 8.0`. Currently we're logging to a plain text file.

My logger is configured as follows:

```cs
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
    .ReadFrom.Services(services)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext());
```

And in application.json:

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using":  [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
  "MinimumLevel": { 
    "Default" : "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Fatal"
    } 
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path":  "./logs/log-.txt", "rollingInterval": "Day" } }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
  "Destructure": [
    { "Name": "ToMaximumDepth", "Args": { "maximumDestructuringDepth": 4 } },
    { "Name": "ToMaximumStringLength", "Args": { "maximumStringLength": 100 } },
    { "Name": "ToMaximumCollectionCount", "Args": { "maximumCollectionCount": 10 } }
  ]
},
```

I was hoping `maximumDestructuringDepth` would cover it, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

This should works for you, config the serilog in your program.cs

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => {
    configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                 .ReadFrom.Services(services)
                 .Enrich.FromLogContext();
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .CreateLogger();
});
```

Create a customize exception formatter

```
public static class CustomExceptionFormatter
{
    public static string FormatException(Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception == null) return string.Empty;

        var stackTrace = new StackTrace(exception, fNeedFileInfo: true);
        var firstFrame = stackTrace.FrameCount > 0 ? stackTrace.GetFrame(0) : null;

        string formattedMessage = $"{exception.Message}";
        if (firstFrame != null)
        {
            formattedMessage += $" at {firstFrame.GetMethod()} in {firstFrame.GetFileName()}:line {firstFrame.GetFileLineNumber()}";
        }
        return formattedMessage;
    }
}
```

And the tester

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Test exception");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var formattedException = CustomExceptionFormatter.FormatException(ex);
            Log.Error(ex, "{FormattedException}", formattedException);
            return Problem(detail: formattedException);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, on the right track.
I've implemented this with a slight tweak - catching exceptions in middleware and using the filter to reformat them, then rethrowing. A more permanent solution will be to log them and return the error status page to the user.